# How to update Circle object on the Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry

In my app, I am displaying a circle around the user. When the user moves, the circle has to move accordingly. Right now to perform that task, I am calling the following function in the `onLocationChange` method:

```
public void drawCircleOnMap(GoogleMap googleMap, double lat, double lng) {
    if(circle != null) {
        circle.remove();
    }
    circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(lat, lng)).radius(CIRCLE_RADIUS)
    .fillColor(Color.argb(100,88, 214, 141)).strokeColor(Color.GREEN));
}
```

However, the problem is, after every update, the circle keeps blinking. I guess deleting itself and then creating a new one. What is the best way to make it go smother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set center property only not remove and draw circle again on position update just set center property like below

```
circle.setCenter(newlatlng)
```

Comment: @YunusKulyyev happy to help you